# How does 'this' keyword in the Base template class of CRTP work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

I have been studying about **CRTP** and what I don't understand is in the main() where we create an object of type `Base<Derived>*` and invoke `callDerived`, how come '`this`' which is an instance of `Base`, has all the information of `Derived` class too? I understand Derived inherits from Base but 'Derived' is juts  template for Base but CRTP works like that is a  two-way inheritance : `Derived` is derived from `Base` and `Base` is also derived from `Derived` while in this line ' Base* pObjBase = new Base();' , '`Derived`' is a just template for `Base`!

I would like to know what is happening behind the scenes that '**this**' has all the information of **Derived**!

```
  #include <iostream>
    template <typename T>
    class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() = default;
        Base()
        {
            std::cout << " Base()\n";
        }
        void callDerived() {
            T& refDerived = static_cast<T&>(*this);
            refDerived.derivedMethod();
    
            T* pDerived = static_cast<T*>(this);
            pDerived->derivedMethod();
    
            //T& obj3 = dynamic_cast<T>(*this); //Error
            //T obj4 = dynamic_cast<T>(*this); //Error
            //obj3.derivedMethod();
            //obj4.derivedMethod();
           
        }
    };
    
    class Derived : public Base<Derived> {
    public:
        Derived() :
            Base()
        {
         
                std::cout << "Derived() \n";
            
        }
        void derivedMethod() {
            std::cout << "Derived method gets invoked" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    
    int main() {
        Base<Derived>* pObjBase = new Base<Derived>();
    
        pObjBase ->callDerived(); // Output: Derived method called
        delete pObjBase ;
    
    }
```

Comment: With CRTP, by convention, you never instantiate just a `Base<T>` by itself. You only instantiate derived types, and also by convention that type always gives its own type as the `T` argument for it's base class `Base<T>`. So `this` always actually points to a `T` as long as you respect the convention.

Comment: CRTP generally works using `static_cast<Derived*>(this)`.

Comment: Your code has UB. This is not how CRTP is supposed to work. You still need a `Derived` object and in your code you don't have one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh! I see! You meant I should always use the following : 
 Derived objDerived;
  objDerived.callDerived(); 

I worked with this one but I was curious about Base<T> . I got it especially the part you said 'this' points to T . there is one thing I don't get it:
"and also by convention that type always gives its own type as the T argument for it's base class Base<T>."

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I knew. But I was curious how come 'this' has information of Derived which was explained above.

Comment: @Evg Thanks for pointing out UB. I had it actually but I removed it as it was clear to me and my question was on Base<T> which turns out that is not how CRTP should be used!

Comment: @Sam "*how come 'this' has information of Derived*" - in this example, it doesn't, actually. Since `this` is not pointing at a `Derived` object, casting `this` to `Derived` is UB. It "works" only because `derivedMethod()` is not accessing any class members via its own `this` pointer, so it doesn't matter that its `this` pointer is being messed up. Change `derivedMethod()` to print a class member, and you will see it crash, or print garbage, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but it prints 'Derived method gets invoked' like the way the following works: (but I can say we shouldn't rely on UB)
 Derived objDerived;
    objDerived.callDerived();

Comment: Try adding an `int` data member into `Derived`, initialize it in `Derived`'s ctor and output its value in `derivedMethod()`.

Comment: Remember `pObj->func()` is (very close to) equivalent at the assembly level to `func(pObj)`.  If `func` never actually dereferences `this` then it will likely never notice that it points to the wrong thing.

Comment: @Evg Thanks. Helpful! I did it . It generated a garbage value '-33686019' and also I used dynamic_cast to see that UB and it crashes "dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pObjBase );" .  dynamic_cast is really helpful to know which line of our code correct with static_cast we can't sometimes figure if casting is correct or not!

Comment: Note that `static_cast` is typically much faster than `dynamic_cast`, so don't use the latter in cases where the former suffice.

Comment: @MilesBudnek you lost me on the part 'If func never actually dereferences this then it will likely never notice that it points to the wrong thing.' how come?

Comment: When you call a non-virtual member function, a compiler doesn't need `this` pointer to call it. `this` pointer is only needed to access data members of an object.

Comment: @Sam Because a pointer is just a memory address.  It could point to anything (or nothing); you'll never know unless you actually follow it and read the memory at that address.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I know understand what you meant on 'Remember pObj->func() is (very close to) equivalent at the assembly level to func(pObj)' , very good point! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because you have to make sure that `T` is the actual type of the object. You don't make a `Base<Derived>` object, because that's the wrong `T` and it's broken, as you thought. What you're supposed to do is make a `Derived` object, which extends from `Base<Derived>`, and all is fine.

The reason you successfully got the message `Derived method gets invoked` has nothing to do with templates or CRTP. It is simply because this function in the compiled code doesn't even touch the object at all. Chances are good that you can call this function on null pointers, or pointers to completely unrelated things, and it will still print the message. "It seems to work properly" is an allowed kind of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But we use polymorphism for CRTP: 

    Base<Derived>* pObjDerived = new Derived();
    pObjDerived->callDerived();
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Derived*>(pObjDerived)->j;

Comment: @Sam that works too, but normally you would write `Derived* pObjDerived = new Derived();`. In both cases the object is a `Derived` so there is no problem

Comment: I have read the second paragraph of your code several times and some parts still confusing to me : 
" It is simply because this function in the compiled code doesn't even touch the object at all." does it mean because inside the function if we for example wanted to print a data member of the class Derived, then the code would crash or if we call another method of Derived class, it would crash, right?

Comment: "Chances are good that you can call this function on null pointers, or pointers to completely unrelated things, and it will still print the message" and this part also confuses me , when i tried to call it on a nullptr it throws error!

Comment: @Sam it has to be a nullptr of the correct type. `Base<Derived>* pObjDerived = nullptr; pObjDerived->callDerived();` is very likely to work. It's not allowed, but the compiler is allowed to not care that it's not allowed, and make it work anyway

Comment: @Sam if you accessed a data member of derived it would be the same as accessing outside of an array

Comment: I did the same but I was experimenting and had added a data member in CallDerived and that's why it throws error and  I removed it and surprisingly it prints the message! That's soooooo insane but interesting that with 'nullptr' it is still working!!! is that all because the compiler knows which one is which at the compile-time and doesn't need to use 'this' to print out the message anymore in run-time?!

Comment: "if you accessed a data member of derived it would be the same as accessing outside of an array" did you mean outside of a class? I don't know why you used 'array' here!

Comment: @Sam Yes, most compilers treat `pObjDerived->callDerived();` as if it was more like `callDerived(pObjDerived);` - they don't care whether `pObjDerived` is null, they just pass null into the function and it works as long as the function doesn't use the null. You're not allowed to rely on this, though - some compilers might care. There's nothing wrong with playing around to see how your compiler works, but remember not to do it in serious programs.

Comment: Thank you so much. I learned a lot from your answers. lots of good points :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        void derivedMethod() {
    a = 3;
    a *= 5;
        std::cout << "Derived method gets invoked, a = " <<a<< std::endl;
    }
```

I add a member "a" to Derived, and the method can print the right value 15, why "a" can be accessed if even the class Derived has not instantiated?